# How can I increment every foreign key in my database?

Tags: mysql

I have two large MySQL databases with identical schemas that I want to merge. To do that I want to increase every foreign key (and id, naturally) of one database by 10 million, and then insert all the records of the modified db into the other db.

I have thought about editing the mysqldump with tools like `grep` and `gawk`, but that seems very hard to do. What would be the best approach?

Comment: I would do the mysql dump with the original data and then change the values in the new database

Comment: If the FK/PK fields have cascading updates, it should be a simple matter to do `update table set pk_field=pk_field+10000000`. The cascade will take care of the foreign keys. Then just dump this db out to a file, and load into the other db.

Comment: The database has 206 tables, with many many FK references. Manually `set`ting fields is not an option.

Comment: @Mark, Great. But how do I handle tables with self-referencing FKs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so here is the solution that I implemented, using the `information_schema` and a bash script. First I get every key-column in the database and the table in which it occurs, and then I update each of those columns.

```bash
echo Incrementing every primary and foreign key by $increment
# Get the table name and column name for every key from the information_schema
select_constraints_sql="select TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME from KEY_COLUMN_USAGE where CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = 'MyDB'"
# Place the query results in an array
data=( $(mysql -e "$select_constraints_sql" -sN --user=$username --password=$passwd information_schema) )

# Step through the tables and keys and update each, with foreign key checks disabled
# Foreign key checks must be disabled at each step
ignore_fks_sql="SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0"
cnt=${#data[@]}
for (( i=0 ; i < cnt ; i=i+2 ))
do
    update_key_sql="$ignore_fks_sql; UPDATE ${data[$i]} SET ${data[$i+1]} = ${data[$i+1]} + $increment"
    mysql -v -e "$update_key_sql" --user=$username --password=$passwd MyDB
done

# This is just me being a bit pedantic
check_fks_sql="SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1"
mysql -v --user=$username --password=$passwd -e "$check_fks_sql" MyDB
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE TABLE mytable_foreign SET ID = ID + 10000000;
UPDATE TABLE mytable SET FOREIGN_ID = FOREIGN_ID + 10000000;
```

In the old DB:

- Drop the constraints on IDs and foreign IDs
- Update the data (using query above)
- Make a backup of the data only as INSERT statements

In the new DB:

- Insert the backup file

Comment: if he's going to merge one into the other, I would drop the constraints. You don't want the overhead of index maintenance, etc while updating millions of rows. He's going to export the data and import into the first database where the appropriate constraints will live on.

Comment: mysqldump --opt database > backup-file.sql (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/mysqldump.html) ?

Comment: that would also include CREATE TABLE statements, right? How do I avoid that? Thanks.

Comment: Read the docs, do some research. Before answering you question I did not know, but it took me 1 minute to find it... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-create-info

Answer (score 1):

Dump two databases into the same server. One will be the target scheme.

- dump database 1 into final_scheme
- dump database 2 into aux_scheme

Do this for every table (I hope it will not be difficult):

```
insert into final_scheme.tableA
   select id+1000000, name, etc, fk_id+1000000 from aux_scheme.tableA
```

I did this for a partial merge (this is, only some tables) and worked fine.